# How do I iterate over *all* values in an array that grows while iterating?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration, dynamic-arrays

The example below won't work because `foreach` works on a copy of the array, but it shows conceptually what I want to achieve.

```
$items = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
foreach ($items as $i) {
  echo $i;
  if ($i === 'c') {
    $items[] = 'e';
  }
}
```

I want this to print '`abcde`', but for the above mentioned reason it only prints '`abcd`'.  I've looked at `array_map` and `array_walk` and others but have not found a solution.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Simple and naive solution: Save array length before the loop, compare after - is it bigger? Then iterate over the newly added elements

Comment: I would call this a race condition

Comment: Not clear why you need this but `while( $counter <= count($arr) )`

Comment: @kingkero the problem is a bit more involved than you seem to think. I also explained why foreach won't work, and that I've looked at other php functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another variation using `while` without the need to count.  Also works with associative arrays and retrieves the key in `$k` if needed:

```
while(list($k, $i) = each($items)) {
  echo $i;
  if ($i === 'c') {
    $items[] = 'e';
  }
}
```

Or using a `for` loop, but this would stop at any element that contained boolean `false` or evaluates to `false`:

```
for($i = reset($items) ; $i ; $i = next($items)) {
```

Comment: Seems to miss the first value 'a'.

Comment: Excellent! This is the elegant answer I was hoping for, thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Added a `for` loop.

Comment: This solution looks very clean, but it assumes that adding items will leave the array pointer unchanged. There seems to be no clear documentation about this behavior, so that feels a bit risky, because it might as well break with a future release of PHP. Do you have any insights or references?

Comment: @GolezTrol the `for` loop with `reset`seems to take care of this, no?

Comment: @Odegard, I meant that maybe `$items[] = ...` might affect the internal pointer of the array. Currently it's not the case, but I'm curious to see some proof that it doesn't just 'accidentally' work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `while` loop (or probably a normal `for` loop too), which evaluates the exit condition after every iteration. Note that in this code, `$i` has changed to be the index, so you use `$items[$i]` to get the actual character.

```
$items = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($items)) {
  echo $items[$i];
  if ($items[$i] === 'c') {
    $items[] = 'e';
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: I think this only works when keys are numerical. What if the keys are strings?

Comment: No matter what keys are count will return the array length.

Comment: @Odegard The array was given. It doesn't have keys. Also `$items[]` doesn't introduce new keys. If you ask a question, please be clear about what you need.

Comment: @Odegard with a tiny modification this works like a charm : http://pastebin.com/UsiJ6Tap

Comment: @Burimi indeed it does. Thanks.